# "live" Phonegap/Titanium app icon

Tags: cordova, titanium

Is it possible to have PhoneGap create a "live" app icon.

This will be a typical icon with a counter, that will periodically call a web serivce to find matches for the users preferences and update the counter.

I have a native Android app that does this so I know it's possible in theory I am just wondering if PhoneGap supports these capabilities?

I would extend this question to Appcelerator Titanium as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS I can tell you that it's not possible to change the App icon which appears on the home screen at runtime. The only thing you can do is to add a badge with your counter to it. Just like in the Mail App or the badge at the Phone App that indicates the number of missed calls.

**Edit:** On iOS it's not possible in general, just to point out that it has nothing to do with PhoneGap/Titanium APIs on iOS.

**Edit 2:**: I just remembered that the only kind of Apps, that can change their App icon are Newsstand Apps. They can change it so their icon reflects the cover of the current issue.